# printing html table extra white spaces at the top

Tags: html

i want to print a html table here is my codes and table ,

https://jsfiddle.net/yc17z1jr/

```
   table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
th,td {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
th {
  background: gray;
}
.page td {
  border-width: 0;
}
.page div {
  page-break-after: always;
}
@media print {
html, body ,table{
  height: auto;   
}
```

as you can see there is extra space at top of the page 3 and 4 what is wrong with my code  ?

thanks .

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the culprit:

```
.page div {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

This rule is declaring that every div that's a child of `.page` will have a page-break space after it. You should place that rule inside:

```
@media print {
    html, body ,table{
       height: auto;   
    }
    .page div {
       page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

[`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) property is intended for printing content, so placing it within your print media query is a logical choice.

Comment: thanks this is not work , but you gave me idea  just 
divide table to smaller tables and put them in div and finally use page-break-after

Comment: That'll work, your plan meets the 2 requirements: 1. break must follow a block-level element  - div ✔ 2. That element must have content. - table ✔